# Scrapy: how to create a dict output with XPATH iterate in a table <tr><td>

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have this html structure:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>....</tr>
    <tr>....</tr>
    <tr>....</tr>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">...</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">...</td>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">...</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">...</td>
    <tr>....</tr>
```

In the table, each tr has 4 td's , i need to create an output dict that the text in the first td is a key, the second a value for that key , the third a new key , and the fourth a value for that key. And do this for every tr in the table.

I tried this in my spider:

this is the XPATH to the table: /html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr

```
def parse(self, response):
        
        for row in response.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr'):

           key1 = row.xpath("/td[0][@align='right']/font[@size='2']/text()").extract()
           value1 = row.xpath("/td[1]/[@bgcolor='#efefef']/descendant::text()").extract()
           key2 = row.xpath("/td[2][@align='right']/font[@size='2']/text()").extract()
           value2 = row.xpath("/td[3]/[@bgcolor='#efefef']/descendant::text()").extract()

            yield{
                key1 : value1,
                key2 : value2
            }
```

Tried this but not working. I'm new to XPATH and scrapy, I don't know how to do this kind of thing. I extracted the keys and values ​​in separate arrays, but this way does not solve my problem, I need to extract them with their respective key-value pair.

Comment: `table[3]` and your sample input mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. You'll probably need to adapt it a bit. Assuming this is your data :

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">a</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">1</td>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">b</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">c</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">3</td>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">d</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">e</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">5</td>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">f</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">g</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">7</td>
      <td align= "right" bgcolor="#ffffff">h</td>
      <td bgcolor="efefef">8</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You can write something like (don't forget the `.` at the beginning of your XPath expression during the loop step) :

```
# Variables declaration, XPath, and loop+fill. We select the keys and the values in each tr at the same time.

key=[]
value=[]
for items in response.xpath("//table/tr"):
    key.append(items.xpath("./td[position()=1 or position()=3]").getall())
    value.append(items.xpath("./td[position()=2 or position()=4]").getall())

# Flatten the lists and extract the text :

keys = [item.text for sublist in key for item in sublist]
values = [item.text for sublist in value for item in sublist]

# Create the dictionnary :

dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dictionary)
```

Output :

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5', 'f': '6', 'g': '7', 'h': '8'}
```

Comment: How can I combine td[position()=1 or position()=3]  with  td[@align='right'] ? With this i will extract exactly the elements i want

Comment: Use  `items.xpath("./td[@align='right']").getall()` and `items.xpath("./td[@bgcolor='efefef']").getall()`. It will be enough.